# Odoo 13 translation not working on website frontend

Tags: python-3.6, odoo-13

I am new to odoo 13 and creating a new custom module, while I working with the translation it behaves differently like if the backend and website frontend was on DE then the translation work perfectly, if I change the backend language to EN and the website frontend was on DE then it shows English contents on the frontend.
Could anyone help me out find the solution?